# What is the cause of "unbound variable" error in this SDL2 Scheme program?

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, lisp, chicken-scheme

I have the below program which is written in Chicken Scheme:

```
(cond-expand
 (chicken-4 (use (prefix sdl2 "sdl2:")))
 (chicken-5 (import (prefix sdl2 "sdl2:"))))

(sdl2:set-main-ready!)
(sdl2:init! '(video))
(define window (sdl2:create-window! "Hello, World!" 0 0 600 400))
(sdl2:fill-rect! (sdl2:window-surface window)
                 #f
                 (sdl2:make-color 0 128 255))
(sdl2:update-window-surface! window)
(sdl2:delay! 3000)
(sdl2:quit!)
```

It is just the [example provided in official Chicken Scheme SDL2 repository](http://wiki.call-cc.org/eggref/5/sdl2). So I consider the code should be valid.

Yet, it throws error as below:

```
(sdl2:quit!)

=> Error: (#f) "unbound variable": (sdl2:quit!)
Call history: 
<eval>   (geiser#geiser-eval (quote #f) (quote (sdl2:quit!)))
<eval>   (write-to-log form)
<eval>   (geiser-chicken-use-debug-log)
<eval>   (call-with-result thunk
```

Answer (score 1):

I just tested this and it works without errors, both in the interpreter and when compiled. I tried in CHICKEN 4 and in CHICKEN 5.

Are you sure you have the latest version of sdl2 installed? Try `chicken-status sdl2`, it should print version 0.3.0.

If that's all fine, maybe there's something weird going on with Geiser, I'm not using that.

Comment: I was doing some sdl2 stuff with chicken scheme the other day, and it looks fine to me too.